# Integral involving unit vectors in spherical coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, integration

I'm puzzled about the value of the following integral, that I've tried to evaluate after turning the unit vectors in spherical coordinates into cartesian coordinates: $I=\int\frac{\hat{r}}{(r-r')^2}d\tau$, where r' is a constant and I'm integrating over the volume of a sphere whose radius is R. I found that the angular integral (the one involving dθ and dϕ) is zero, while the other blows up (r′<R, so I get a form 0⋅∞)

Comment: Clarify one point: is $r'$ a constant? or you mean a constant vector $\int\int\int \frac{\hat{r}}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|^2} d\tau$. If it is a constant, that means a spherical shell.  Which one is your purpose?

Comment: $r'$ is a scalar constant

Comment: What is the origin of this integral? Somewhat strange for $r'$ to be a scalar constant.

Answer (score 1):

Any integral of this form is zero by symmetry (assuming it converges).

Consider

$$
\mathbf{I} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} dv\, \mathbf{r} f(r)$$

Now, rotate $\mathbf{I}$ with an arbitrary matrix $M$ in $O(3)$

\begin{align}
M \mathbf{I} &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} dv\, f(r) M \mathbf{r} \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} dv\, f( \Vert M^t \mathbf{y} \Vert)  \mathbf{y} \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} dv\, f(y)  \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{I}
\end{align}

Where I changed to coordinates $\mathbf{y} =M\mathbf{r} $ and used the fact that the Jacobian of the transformation is one.

Since $\mathbf{I} $ is a vector which is invariant under any rotation it must be the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

The integral

$$
I = \int\int\int \frac{\hat{r}}{(r-\xi)^2} d^3r
$$

Express the integrand as a gradient form:
$$
\frac{\hat{r}}{|r-\xi|^2} = -\vec{\nabla}_r \frac{1}{(r-\xi)}
$$

Then, using the alternated form of divergent theorem $ \int\int\int_V \vec{\nabla}f d^3r = \oint\oint_S f d\vec{S}$ [divergent theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergenceTheorem.html)
$$
I = \int\int\int -\vec{\nabla}_r \frac{1}{(r-\xi)} d^3r = -\oint\oint_S \frac{d\vec{s}}{(R-\xi)}=-\frac{1}{(R-\xi)}\oint\oint_S d\vec{s}= 0.
$$

Examine the divergent part of the integrand $\xi-\delta < r < \xi+\delta$.
$$
I(\xi) = \int_{\xi-\delta}^{\xi+\delta} r^2dr \frac{1}{(r-\xi)^2} \int\int d\Omega  \hat{r} = \xi^2 \frac{2}{\delta} 0 = 0
$$
Both methods give $I=0$. If $\xi$ is a scalar number, then the sperical symmetry of the integrand makes the $\hat{r}$ integral over the spherical angle $d\Omega = \sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ vanishes.